# Deezer API - get large cover

Tags: deezer

I'm trying to get a larger version of cover from Deezer's API. From [what I read](http://developers.deezer.com/api/album), adding `size/big` shoul suffice, but it doesn't - I get error in return. What can I do?

My current URL is `https://api.deezer.com/album/302127/image/size/big`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the correct format for the url : https://api.deezer.com/album/302127/image?size=big